# Two Way SSL Authentication in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, openssl, ssl-certificate, client-certificates, pkcs#12

I am trying to integrate with a 3rd party API using two way SSL authentication. The documention provided by them is for **JAVA** and I am using **NodeJS**. I am new to this and really grasping at straw here. In document it is mentioned to generate a self signed certificate and use private key of that certificate with the public cetificate from them to create a PKCS 12 file and use it to call the API.

Below is the excerpt from the documentation to

*Create a self signed certificate*

> `keytool -genkey -keyalg RSA -alias <aliasName>-keystore selfsigned.jks -validity <days> -keysize 2048`

*Import JKS to key store*

> 1. KeyDBs could be any format PFX, JKS or P12. Listing the certificates from > the Keystores, Go to bin directory of Java library, It should have a Private-> Cert entry in the List of the certificates.
>      `Keytool  -list -v -keystore <Keystore Name>`
> 2. If the KeyDB is not present create a Keydb using the Private key and Public Certificate provided through openSSL.
>
>    - Create P12 from key
>        `openssl pkcs12 -export -in mycert.crt -inkey <mykey.key> -out mycert.p12 -name tomcat -CAfile  <myCA.crt> -caname root –chain`
>    - Create JKS from P12
>        `keytool -v -importkeystore -srckeystore <key.p12> -srcstoretype PKCS12 -destkeystore <key.jks> -deststoretype JKS`
> 3. To Verify: KeyDBs could be any format PFX, JKS or P12. Listing the certificates from the Keystores, Go to bin directory of Java library, It should have a Private-Cert entry in the List of the certificates.
>      `Keytool  -list -v -keystore <Keystore Name>`

I am facing problem in creating the PKCS 12 file. I created self signed certificate using openssl (provided with git) via below mentioned commmands

*Creating request and private key*

`openssl req -new -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -keyout privatekey.key -out certificatereq.cer`

*Creating Certificate using the request and key*

`openssl x509 -req -days 365 -in certificatereq.cer -signkey privatekey.key -out selfsigned.crt`

Upon creation of certificate I used it to create PKCS 12 file as mentioned in documentation above via below mentioned command

`openssl pkcs12 -export -in  selfsigned.crt -inkey privatekey.key -out outpkcs12file.p12 -name myname -CAfile thirdpartypublic.crt -caname mycaname -chain`

but getting the error **Error self signed certificate getting chain**. I tried by installing the self signed certificate in my system also and getting the same error. If I remove the -chain (*not sure what it does, but found few commands without -chain*) agrument there is no output in terminal. The third party's certificate is CA signed.

Comment: Did you find a solution this issue?

Comment: Not yet. Found a link to implement two way ssl in nodejs http://www.developerdave.co.uk/2014/10/two-way-ssl-node-js/ but that also didn't work.